# DatabaseException unrecognized token: "1ter"

Tags: android, sql, flutter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не читает базу данных. Может не правильно указал путь , пробовал- `String path = join(await getDatabasesPath(), '1test.db');`

Comment: Что код, что ошибки/логи следует прикладывать в виде кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте путь к файлу в pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  # ...
  assets:
    - assets/1test.db
```

Используйте [rootBundle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/rootBundle.html) чтобы загрузить его:

```
return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/1test.db');
```

Дальше делайте что хотите, но скорее всего вам нужно будет сохранять содержимое файла, по этому [вот как это можно делать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384175/sqlite-in-flutter-how-database-assets-work/51387985#51387985). А еще лучше использовать ORM, например [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor).